# How should I understand "à" in "ma porte à clef"?

Tags: grammaire, sens, prépositions

> Le soir suivant, je voulus faire la même épreuve. *Je fermai donc **ma
>   porte à clef** pour être certain que personne ne pourrait pénétrer chez moi.*
>   Je m'endormis et je me réveillai comme chaque nuit. On avait bu toute
>   l'eau que j'avais vue deux heures plus tôt.

In the second sentence of the excerpt above, what is the grammatical property of "à" there? My dictionary shows that it is a preposition. But there is no definite/indefinite article in front of "clef". Is "porte à clef" a phrase or something?

My question concerns that how should I understand "Je fermai donc ma porte à clef" precisely in English.

Comment: The phrase is *fermer à clef* and means "to lock" when the lock opens with a key. See http://french.stackexchange.com/q/19427/10519 for a much more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*fermer à clef* means to lock something. You can also use *fermer à clé* with exactly the same meaning, since clé and clef are synonymous. It's worth noting that even though these both literally mean  "close by key", there does not have to be a key envolved in the locking process, for example you could use fermer à clé when referring to a toilet cubicle door, which doesn't use a key. *(It may be useful if some natives confirm this, but I'm pretty sure this is the case)*

Another verb for to lock would be verrouiller, but fermer à clé is probably more common in everyday language.

In answer to your other question, you would translate that phrase as

> I will therefore lock my door.... (to be certain that nobody can get into my house)

Comment: I'm a native and I wouldn't mind using "*fermer à clef*" for a toilet cubicle door... even though I would naturally use *verrouiller* in most cases where a key is not involved.

Comment: clé et clef ne sont pas des synonymes, mais deux orthographes possibles du même mot.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina ahh merci, alors est-ce que les deux mots ont la même prononciation aussi?

Comment: @Harvey - également. Il y a seulement quelques mots dans ce cas: cuillère/cuiller, orang-outan/outang, paie, paye,tsar/tzar, yogourt, yoghourt

Answer (score 0):

**à** est associé à *fermer*, et non à *porte*. Cela signifie *avec* dans ce cas.

- fermer à clef : avec une clef
- fermer à double tour : avec / en faisant un double tour
- fermer à fond : jusqu'au fond
- fermer à mort (forme familière) : jusqu'à la mort (jusqu'au bout, au maximum)